# Show different content in a table cell

Tags: css

I am trying to hide content in a table cell with css and display some dots or stars instead.
I have tried this

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}
td {
  font-size: 0
}
td::after {
  content: '*****';
  font-size: 1em
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

but this does not work, it seems that font-size 0 in 'td' overwrites the one in 'td::after'

Unfortunatelly I can't put a span element or so inside the td due to visual editor limitations.

Any ideas?

Comment: `1em` is a relative `font-size` based on the `font-size` of its parent; try `font-size: 1rem` (or `15px`, `1ch`, `2vmin`...effectively any font-size unit that's not based on the inherited font-size). It's worth adding, though, that this method of "hiding" isn't going to achieve much since the text is still present in the DOM, and is accessible to screen readers, and so forth.

Comment: thanks, yeah it's fine for my use case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use *rem* instead of *em* to overwrite the font size. *em* is relative to the font size of the parent element. *rem* instead is relative to the font size of the root element.

```
td::after {
  content: '*****';
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```